# Right way to mysql character insert with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

With whatever I do (php & meta Content-type headers as utf-8) and all the htmlspecialchars, utf8_de- and encode etc. I just can't seem to insert text the right way into the table.
Even returning it in a div, checking with alerts etc. nothing seems to get this right:

This is inserted into the MySQL table:

```
Americaâ€™s Greatest Rock â€˜Nâ€™ Roll Band â€“ have
```

it should be:

```
America’s Greatest Rock ‘N’ Roll Band – have
```

in the jQuery script I use:

```
var ch_title = encodeURIComponent(ch_title);
var ch_descr = encodeURIComponent(ch_descr);
```

the PHP insert script has:

```
$ch_descr = "$_POST[ch_descr]";
$ch_descr = nl2br("$ch_descr");
$ch_descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$ch_descr);
```

Does anyone know how to get this right?

**Solution**
I used this to solve the problem, including the doctype and headers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and for PHP:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$ch_descr = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ch_descr);
$ch_descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$ch_descr);
```

Comment: Also why are you wrapping your variables in double quotes all the time? `$ch_descr = "$_POST[ch_descr]";` can be simply `$ch_descr = $_POST['ch_descr'];`

Comment: Thanks, but your comment and duplication article doesn't really tell what to do how to fix this. All the (uni)codes in the database are already correct.

Comment: Is your php file also utf-8 encoded?

Comment: yes it is! with php header and meta

Comment: No I mean the physical `xxx.php` file i.e. the php source code file

Comment: it is now! Changed it with textpad.

Comment: I fixed it with: $ch_descr = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ch_descr); $ch_descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$ch_descr); Thanks for your efforts @RiggsFolly !